# When to consider controlling for confounding variables and how to go about it

Tags: regression, confounding, controlling-for-a-variable, elections

[David Greenwald](http://davidgreenwald.com), writer, photographer and cat owner from Portland, Oregon, [tweeted on Nov. 11](https://twitter.com/i/moments/797121503783329792) that there could have been some discrepancies in swing states between counties using electronic and paper ballots. This is captured on today's web edition of [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/nov/23/hillary-clinton-election-vote-recount-michigan-pennsylvania-wisconsin), together with a link on some [tweets by Nate Silver](https://twitter.com/NateSilver538/status/801221907609579520), including his regression analysis as follows:

> Run a regression on Wisc. counties with >=50K people, and you find
>   that Clinton improved more in counties with only paper ballots.
>   HOWEVER:

[image]

> ...the effect COMPLETELY DISAPPEARS once you control for race and
>   education levels, the key factors in predicting vote shifts this year.

[image]

Nobel laureate [Paul Krugman](https://twitter.com/paulkrugman/status/801235511394308096) seemingly closed the loop... on tweeter... by saying:

> The response from Nate was exactly what we needed. I personally wanted
>   real reasons to dismiss this scare, *not* "don't be silly" 2/

It seems silly, almost, now, and in retrospect, but there is already a [letter to Congress](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdwQa-5YTdMJP4U1mqRLihr1wG4Kz8Nw58lTGFabrcZprUkYw/viewform?c=0&w=1) signed by the who's who of higher education.

So perhaps it is not so self-evident after all, and I would like to ask for some **senior comment as to when is it necessary to consider controlling for [confounding variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding), and how a seasoned statistician goes about it.** In the end it is really impressive how a quick OLS is likely to have put an end to a looming conspiracy theory.

Comment: Please note that this is meant as a CW post intended to deepen the understanding of a current event likely being followed by millions of people, and finding its resolution in the understanding of basic statistical concepts.

Comment: Please search our site for "Simpson's Paradox."

Comment: @whuber I'll take advantage of this interchange to wish you a Happy TxGiving tomorrow (and will erase this promptly). You know, I have even posted some entries of my own doing about Simpson's paradox (probably too scrappy to mention, but just to say that I actually have searched CV for some pearls on the topic - a very good one recently by Pere off the top of my head), but especially when there is no contingency table (proportions or counts) I still have nagging doubts as to whether it's confounding  or Simpson's, as in this [post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19529/67822).

Comment: Thank you @Antoni for your kind thoughts.  I believe Simpson's Paradox can be construed in general as a confounding phenomenon.  Even if you wish to maintain a strict construction of it as concerning contingency tables only, it occurred to me that nevertheless the same considerations apply: the decision to adjust for confounding variables seems to be the same as the decision to break a table down by the individual values of some factor.  In both situations, the results and the interpretation can change profoundly.  That's why I was hoping a search might turn up directly useful posts.

Comment: @whuber Great, thank you. I'll keep the question open, then, since it seems to me after reading your comment, that there is room for someone to elaborate on these points. I realize that it is a very soft question, and it's very general, but it blew my mind seeing such a simple OLS dispel concerns that were taking a somber tone, and with so many "macro" considerations.